# I would like to simulate spiky ocean waves from an old animated cartoon

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

Recently I watched a German movie called Käpt'n Blaubär: Der Film. I loved this movie as a child and when I re-watched it I was really impressed with the wave physics. They are unrealistic and over the top spiky but that's what I like about them. I have attached a YouTube link where the waves can be seen. My goal is to recreate them in Blender, and although I have some modeling experience, I have never worked with physics and liquids so I do not know how to approach this project. Is there any modifier I could use for this or maybe a displacement map? I would appreciate some help with this!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3yK-LWCCQY&feature=youtu.be

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Would this be close enough?
[image]

How it looks when animated:

[image]

The Ocean Modifier creates a pretty realistic wavy sea, and the Simple Deform modifier enhances the vertical component.

Comment: Hi, sometimes even youtube links go down, would you care to elaborate on the answer? Answers that rely on links are generally discouraged, the link should be supportive of the content in the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: the link is merely showing the moving ocean effect (since I can't upload a video here), it's not the whole answer.
the actual answer is clear enough, I hope - two simple modifiers. But I guess I can improve that.

Comment: @CBarr only as an animated gif.

Comment: fixed it! 
I didn't know GIFs could be used as images, cool.

Comment: @CBarr much better:) thanks for the edit